# Finding branches of $(z-1)^{2/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we determine all branches of $(z-1)^{2/3}$ ? I see some examples of complex square root function and logarithm but still I have some confusions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $z=1$ is the branch point. So take any ray with initial point as $z=1$, which will be branch cuts for different branches of the required multi variable function.

Comment: In a sense $z=\infty$ is the second branch point. So any curve that connects $z=1$ to $z=\infty$ and does not self-intersect is a valid branch cut.

Comment: Yes I did only in finite complex plane...

Comment: If $Z=z-1$ then each branch of $Z^{2/3}$ yields a branch of $(z-1)^{2/3}$. Let $Z=|Z|.e^{i\theta}$. So a branch of $(z-1)^{2/3}$ is $f_1(z)=|z-1|^{2/3}e^{i\frac{2}{3}\theta}$ where $\theta=arg(z-1)$ and $0<\theta<2\pi$. Is it right?